# HOW TO Set the Picture resolution in webcam photo in WebCam_Capture.dll or any other dll

Tags: vb.net, photo

HOW TO Set the Picture resolution in webcam photo in  WebCam_Capture.dll or any other dll

i save the photo but it is low quality but webcam is 20 pixel how to save it in good resolution please suggest the dll

Comment: Can you give me `WebCam_Capture.dll` download link?

Comment: http://api.256file.com/webcam_capture.dll/en-download-10371.html

Comment: Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports WebCam_Capture
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Comment: If there any dll to use please suggest me for best quality it is for product item photo

Comment: You want to record video or pictures?